# Error with pointcloud_to_laserscan and rviz

Tags: rviz, laser, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I'm trying to convert a point cloud to a fake laser scan and then visualize it with rviz. For doing that, first I use the pointcloud_to_laserscan stack. I think I have no problem with this part because with rostopic echo I can see a list of points of the laser scan, and all seems right.

The problem starts when I try to visualize this fake laser with rviz. I add a new LaserScan display and I put the topic of the laser scan converted. When I do that, the display status changes to "Error" and I get this warning message on the console:

```
[ WARN] [1349860717.340263739, 12012.394000000]: MessageFilter [target=/map ]: Dropped 100,00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.rviz.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
```

Does anyone know why I get this error?

For more detail, there's how I convert the point_cloud to a fake laser scan:

```
  <!-- openni_manager -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="openni_manager" output="screen" respawn="true" args="manager"/> 

     <!-- fake laser -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="kinect_laser" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager">
    <param name="output_frame_id" value="/openni_depth_frame"/>
    <param name="range_max" value="10.0"/>
    <param name="range_min" value="0.4"/>
    <param name="angle_max" value="0.383972435"/>
    <param name="angle_min" value="-0.383972435"/>
    <remap from="cloud" to="/tof_camera/depth/points"/>
    <remap from="scan" to="tof_camera/fake_laser"/>
  </node>
```

I'm in Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Fuerte. Thanks in advance. Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45482/error-with-pointcloud_to_laserscan-and-rviz/) by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2012-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's your target frame in rviz? I guess it's map and you don't have map in your TF tree. Try changing it, for instance to `openni_detph_frame`.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) on 2012-10-10**:
Wow, I'm stupid... I've added the openni_detph_frame to my TF tree and now all works. I forgot to add it and that was the problem. Thank you for your answer, and sorry for this stupid question ;)